# Entitlement to China visa while on a tourist visa of Macau

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, china, macau

I am in Macau on a tourist visa on an Indian passport. May I apply for a Chinese tourist visa from Macau?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may but evidence suggests it does not make sense. In general Chinese embassies prefer you apply from your home country or your country of residence (proof of residence required/asked for).

Hong Kong (and maybe similarly Macau) used to be a loophole around this with quick and inexpensive visas for China, but this since has changed, see [here](http://www.saporedicina.com/english/get-a-chinese-visa-in-hong-kong/) for HK. [This site](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/application.htm) suggests the current situation is similar in Macau. 
I also found [this reference](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g664891-i12409-k4925761-Getting_a_visa_for_China_when_in_Macau-Macau.html) which I assume to be outdated given the above and suggest not to rely on.

In short, you would likely be better off to apply for a China-visa from your home-country. If applying from Macau, allow for plenty of time, expect to pay decent fees and be aware that most likely you would have to apply through a local visa agency.

Comment: Saporedicina.com suggests it's still possible for a non-resident to get a visa in Hong Kong. Could you quote the part which confirms the loophole is now closed?

Comment: @JonathanReez this answer of mine might be outdated but I don't have the time to check in depth right now. I will remove my comment from your other A, thanks for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 1):

IF your plan is just to "dip your toes" in China , than yes, you could get a special 3 days visa on arrival ( restricted to Zuhai area only ! ) in the GongBei boarder.
I am not sure if you can do this if this is your FIRST visit to China , But I myself did it 3 or 4 times .
Note that in some periods ( like Chinese national Holidays ) this service will not be available .
If you plan a long trip, than it will be more complicated .
Nowadays the Macau officers will check for your Chinese Visa BEFORE exiting macau and it will depend on the officer itself to decide if to let you pass if you say you want to try the "restricted visa on arrival"